# In javascript how to add or remove 's' from a quantity string

Tags: javascript, string, replace, conditional-statements

I have a string that's returned from the database such as `7 Months 5 Days`.

The issue is when it's 1 Month 1 Day, it's still showing as `1 Months 1 Days`, notice the letter `s` in `Months` and `Days`.

And I'm not allowed to use brackets like this `1 Month(s) 1 Day(s)`.

Please how can I make a condition that if it's less than 2 Days then remove the `s`?

The below is not working. What do I do?

JS

```
var YYMM = '1 Months 1 Days'; // simulated data.

if (YYMM.indexOf('1') > -1) {
  YYMM.replace('s', '');

  console.log('YYMM is: ', YYMM);
}
```

Many Thanks

Comment: That's another issue. I just wanna deal with 1 Day for now... :)

Comment: The actual problem should be solved before you finally generate the "simulated data" #performance

Comment: I'm not in charged with the data/database/backend and it's an old system, so I just wanna know how to deal with this for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single regexp with replace can do it:

```js
var reg = /\b1\b\s(Month|Day)s/g;
alert( '1 Months 1 Days'.replace(reg, '1 $1') );
alert( '11 Months 21 Days'.replace(reg, '1 $1') );
alert( '12 Months 1 Days'.replace(reg, '1 $1') );
```

Comment: And what happens with `'11 Months 21 Days'`? Not the right thing, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you! Fixed.. Hopefully this way it covers all cases.

Answer (score 2):

It's just one case, so:

```
'1 Months 1 Days'.replace(/\b1 Months/, '1 Month')
                 .replace(/\b1 Days/, '1 Day');
```

will work.

```js
document.getElementById('div1').textContent 
    = '1 Months 1 Days'.replace(/\b1 Months/, '1 Month')
                       .replace(/\b1 Days/, '1 Day');

document.getElementById('div2').textContent 
    = '12 Months 21 Days'.replace(/\b1 Months/, '1 Month')
                       .replace(/\b1 Days/, '1 Day');
```

```html
1 Months 1 Days -->
<div id="div1"></div>

12 Months 21 Days -->
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply split the string and concat after changing the string, like this

```
var YYMM = '1 Months 1 Days';
YYMM = YYMM.split(' ');

if (parseInt(YYMM[0], 10) < 2) {
    YYMM[1] = 'Month';
}

if (parseInt(YYMM[2], 10) < 2) {
    YYMM[3] = 'Day';
}

YYMM = YYMM.join(' ');
console.log(YYMM);
# 1 Month 1 Day
```

The advantage of this, it is readily understandable. But you can write the `if` conditions with ternary operator, like this

```
YYMM[1] = 'Month' + (parseInt(YYMM[0], 10) < 2 ? '' : 's');
YYMM[3] = 'Day'   + (parseInt(YYMM[2], 10) < 2 ? '' : 's');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var str = '1 Months 3 Days';
var parts = str.split(' ');

if(parts[0] === '1') {
  parts[1] = parts[1].slice(0, -1);
}

if(parts[2] === '1') {
  parts[3] = parts[3].slice(0, -1);
}

var result = parts.join(' ');
```